# Why is the Profiler module in Ruby 1.9 named with two trailing underscores?

Tags: ruby, ruby-1.9

I looked through the standard library and Profiler__ is the only module I can find that uses two underscores in the name like that. Is there a reason?

Comment: @nash My working theory is that a Python developer infiltrated the core team but I was hoping to hear otherwise.

Comment: My guess is that it was because "Profiler" is a not-uncommon name in programming terms, and the original author was trying to be cautious (in a rather geeky way) to avoid namespace collisions. Perhaps super-old versions of Ruby didn't provide any module namespacing and this predates that.

Comment: I hope you are wrong. I don't want to see indentation rules in my ruby code. :)

Comment: @nash: You're 100% right! You can see a photo of him at http://www.flickr.com/photos/john_lam/1910968816/ . @nash: If you turn on warnings, it gives you warnings about incorrect indentation.

Answer (score 1):

Because in the Ruby core GC has a Profiler class.

[GC::Profiler](http://rubydoc.info/stdlib/core/1.9.2/GC/Profiler)

[Profiler](http://rubydoc.info/stdlib/profiler/1.9.2/Profiler__)

This is the only reason I can think of. I don't really see a reason why though, as the Profiler class in the Ruby core is "namespaced" under the GC module...